# start/stop tomcat using maven

Tags: maven-2, ant

How can i start/stop remote tomcat using maven. I am using cargo plugin which helps me in deploying the application , but doesn't provides the functionality to start/stop the remote tomcat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use the [maven tomcat plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/tomcat-maven-plugin/context-goals.html) or if it does not give you everything you need, you can always use an ant task here is a [reference on the task](http://www.coderanch.com/t/107952/Ant-Maven-Other-Build-Tools/Starting-stopping-Tomcat-from-Ant)

Comment: just see the links and you will understand.

Comment: There is **nothing** about starting/stopping a remote tomcat in the links.

Answer (score 7):

Indeed, You can NOT start and stop Tomcat running remotely using Cargo, only deploy and undeploy your web application.

Actually, to my knowledge, there is currently *nothing* allowing to do this out of the box.

As explained [here](http://www.jguru.com/forums/view.jsp?EID=1364036), *the only way to make server "A" start or stop a service like Tomcat when the request comes from client "B" is that yet-another service needs to be available and already running on server "A". [...]* and I don't know if such a service is available.

In this [message](http://marc.info/?l=tomcat-user&m=108604401026298&w=2), someone is describing such a solution (based on a socket listener) that you could maybe use (by doing some telnet through maven) but the message is quite old so it's likely outdated and the link pointing to the code seems to be dead. I didn't check out the whole thread, maybe there are other ideas.

If you are using windows, remote service sharing is another possible solution as described [here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/84890/Tomcat/Start-Shutdown-Tomcat-Remotely). But, again, this would require some work on your side.

Answer (score 6):

From a security standpoint, it's only possible in this way...

Linux: use an SCP or script via SSH Client (putty), then '$CATALINA_HOME/bin/shutdown.sh'

Windows: use sc command, like "sc \192.168.10.10 stop tomcat6"

Quick and clean!

Comment: You can easily do SCP and SSH with ANT. Just use SCP and SSHExec tasks, and be happy!

Answer (score 1):

You can use Cargo Daemon web-application. It runs on the remote machine and can start/stop tomcat for you (as well as deploy an app). You just need to configure Cargo plugin and call mvn:daemon-start. Here is the link: http://cargo.codehaus.org/Cargo+Daemon. It's easier to start with provided Cargo Daemon archetype: http://cargo.codehaus.org/Maven2+Archetypes#Maven2Archetypes-daemon

Answer (score -2):

Try this [useful Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/tomcat-maven-plugin/context-goals.html)

Afterwards try this:

```
mvn tomcat:start
```

and

```
mvn tomcat:stop
```

Comment: This won't start/stop a **remote** tomcat

Comment: This onyl starts and stops the application configured in the pom.xml, not the server itself

Comment: This is only for embeeded options, plugin on Maven. Works well, but if you need complex configuration at your Tomcat, is not an option.